# Integral domain containing non-prime irreducibles (hence not a UFD) where all factorizations into irreducibles are unique

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

An integral domain is called a UFD if

(1) every non-zero non-unit element factors into irreducibles, and

(2) every element that factors into irreducibles does so uniquely (up to units and order).

It is known that being a UFD implies

($\ast$) every irreducible is prime.

It is also known that an integral domain that satisfies ($\ast$) must satisfy (2).

I am asking for examples of integral domains where (2) holds but ($\ast$) does **not**.

In other words, I am asking for integral domains that (A) contains some irreducibles that are not prime and where (B) every element that has a factorization into irreducibles has a unique factorization into irreducibles.

Such an example cannot be a UFD. It cannot be a GCD domain. It cannot be a Noetherian domain. It cannot be an atomic domain.

Comment: I would look into stuff like the ring of entire functions in one variable. Here, the main obstruction to being UFD is having entire functions with infinitely many zeros, meaning infinitely many irreducible factors - but a factorization must be finite. For example, $\sin\pi z = \pi z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Thanks. A reasonable suggestion. I already did. The ring of entire functions is a Bezout domain, hence a GCD domain, hence satisfies (*). So it won't work.

Comment: That's too bad. All the other potential examples that come to mind have no irreducibles at all, which vacuously satisfies (*). Do you have any examples of domains with irreducibles (that may be prime) satisfying $(2)$ but not $(1)$?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim The ring of entire functions satisfies (2) but not (1). The ring of polynomials with rational coefficients and integer constant coefficient ($\mathbb{Z} + x\mathbb{Q}[x]$) has the same properties. Both are Bezout domains.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Something else noteworthy: If $R$ has no irreducibles and $R$ is not a field, then $R[x]$ has irreducibles and does not satisfy (1).

Comment: Thank you, those are good examples. Will $R[x]$ ever help, i.e., if $R$ has no irreducibles, will $R[x]$ ever introduce non-prime irreducibles? $x$, for example, will be prime if $R$ is a domain.